# Polars map users with more than one event

Tags: python, python-polars

```
df = pl.LazyFrame({'col1':['a','a','b','b','c','c'],'col2':['undefined','defined','defined','defined','undefined','undefined']})
```

I have the following DF

Imagine I want to select the rows where col2 has more than two different values when it is grouped by col1.
And I want to select those users and map them in a way I know they have more than two different values in col 2.

Wanted result

```
df = pl.LazyFrame({'col1':['a','a','b','b','c','c'],'col2':['undefined','defined','defined','defined','undefined','undefined'],'col3':[2,2,1,1,1,1]})
```

Any ideas on how can I achieve that? In a efficient manner avoiding lefts joins separate filters and so on

Comment: Incase it's useful: *"The joins are one of the most optimized algorithms in polars."* - https://stackoverflow.com/a/74673927

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like [`.n_unique()`](https://pola-rs.github.io/polars/py-polars/html/reference/expressions/api/polars.Expr.n_unique.html#polars.Expr.n_unique)

```py
df.with_columns(col3 = pl.col("col2").n_unique().over("col1"))
```

```py
shape: (6, 3)
┌──────┬───────────┬──────┐
│ col1 ┆ col2      ┆ col3 │
│ ---  ┆ ---       ┆ ---  │
│ str  ┆ str       ┆ u32  │
╞══════╪═══════════╪══════╡
│ a    ┆ undefined ┆ 2    │
│ a    ┆ defined   ┆ 2    │
│ b    ┆ defined   ┆ 1    │
│ b    ┆ defined   ┆ 1    │
│ c    ┆ undefined ┆ 1    │
│ c    ┆ undefined ┆ 1    │
└──────┴───────────┴──────┘
```

You may want to also try `.unique().len()` as there was a previous report `n_unique` about performance: https://github.com/pola-rs/polars/issues/11249

Not sure if those benchmarks are still relevant.